# Не обновляются данные в UITableView

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, uicollectionview

Всем привет!

У меня есть `UITableView`, в ячейках которого находятся `UICollectionView`.
Первоначально у меня запускается приложение и загружает все данные, затем передает данные по классам и отображаются данные в этом `UITableView`.

Проблема заключается в том, что повторно обновить данные не перезаходя в приложение у меня не получается.

Система такая -

1). Приложение запустилось, сработал метод парсинга данных с Firebase database, 
все инициализировал и данные есть в `UICollectionViewCell`.

2). Нажимаю на кнопку геопозиции и открывается `ChangeGeoTableViewController` , где я выбираю город, этот контроллер закрывается (`self.dismiss`) и на прошлом `VC` срабатывает делегат - начинается выгрузка из `Firebase Database`, после парсинга данные я передаю в массивы и должны передаться в ячейку, где находится `UICollectionView` -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: checkBrand, for: indexPath) as! CheckBrandTableViewCell
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: lastPostsID, for: indexPath) as! LastPostsTableViewCell
        cell.lastPosts = self.lastPosts
        return cell // и так далее
```

В конечном итоге использую

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Но данные в таблице, коллекции не меняются.

То есть проблема просто заключается в том, что я вроде бы передаю данные в массивы, в них там все новое лежит, но данные в таблице не обновляются.

Может не срабатывает по-новому `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Если вопрос решен, пометьте ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Необходимо было добавить в метод `cellForRorAtIndexPath` -

```
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```